# Why are there gaps between Column's Text and TextField children? (How to remove the gaps?)

Tags: flutter

This is how the gaps look like
[awkward gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3D99.png)

I want to remove the gaps.
The image I attached is from a pop-up modal, and here's how the content look like:

```
Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.67,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.50,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text("Kode Indikator",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                    height:40,
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        labelText: dataList[index].xxtsmkKode,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text("Kriteria",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                    height:40,
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        labelText: dataList[index].xxtsmkKriteria,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text("Grup Indikator",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                    height:40,
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        labelText: dataList[index].xxtsmiGroupIndikator,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text("Indikator",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                    height:40,
                    child: TextField(
                      readOnly: true,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                        labelText: dataList[index].xxtsmiIndikator,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

              ],),
              Column(
                children: const [

                  Expanded(
                    child: Text("Kode Indikator",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                  )
              ],),


          ]
        )
        )
```

I'll appreciate it if you can also help me on layouting tips, as I'm still new with Flutter and how to make this layout with the gaps between textfield-text instead of text-textfield right now. I think I've been using Expanded and Flexible wrongly but I don't know exactly.

I tried using Stack widget, but ended up with the elements on top of each other.

EDIT:
Ok so after more trying, I figured out it's because of the Expanded taking up as many space as possible. When I changed Expanded to SizedBox it finally looked like what I wanted.
But I still want to know if it's possible to do it without SizedBox, as I hard-coded the height..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove expanded Widget and remove gap.
Like this

```
Container(
      child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
    Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          "Kode Indikator",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          height: 40,
          child: const TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              labelText: 'a',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Text(
          "Kriteria",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          height: 40,
          child: const TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              labelText: 'a',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Grup Indikator",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          height: 40,
          child: const TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              labelText: 'b',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          "Indikator",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
          height: 40,
          child: const TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              labelText: 'c',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    const Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          "Kode Indikator",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ]))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. This really is a newbie mistake.. I appreciate the codes.

Comment: Thank you . if u learn to more understanding expanded , row and column can u read below link. I hope it is more useful for you.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The gaps are there because you use `Expanded`. `Expanded` makes it that all available space gets divided between all the `Expanded` in the `Column`. Just use `Text` directly without wrapping them in `Expanded`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Every time I don't use expanded inside row/column, I'll get "Error: no size" or something to the point that I thought it's mandatory. Please excuse my newbie question.